# Cost Allocation Tags in services already created

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to use "Cost Allocation Tags" in AWS but the documentation says the following:

> AWS-generated cost allocation tags aren't applied to resources that were created before the tag was activated.

Is there a solution to assign tags to already created resources?

I was trying to cross data between the cost report that can be obtained from AWS and a python script to associate the cost of each resource, but some items do not allow me to deduct the cost of use that they have.

Comment: How's it going? Are you still unclear what to do?

Answer (score 0):

This means you can still add tags manually and create tags yourself. It just says that AWS will not go through your already existing resources and try to assign tags to them